# Invisible BLE device when Qt scanning

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new on Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device development and I have to develop an HMI (on Windows 10) which is able to communicate with the BLE device.

For this purpose, I choose to develop my SW with Qt v5.14.2 which includes API for Bluetooth communication.

I'm in the first step, which is scanning devices around me. For this test, I have some standard Bluetooth devices around and also a BLE dev kit (Nordic nRF52) that advertise permanently.

My problem is that: when I run my code, I can find standard Bluetooth devices around but not the BLE device.. (With another app I can find it all..).

Here is my code:
1) My constructor which initialize the Bluetooth com and start it:

```
CemBluetooth::CemBluetooth(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent();
    discoveryAgent -> setLowEnergyDiscoveryTimeout(10000); // in ms

    connect(discoveryAgent, SIGNAL(deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo&)), this, SLOT(addDevice(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo&)));
    connect(discoveryAgent, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(f_ctrl_bl_scanBlDevicesFinished()));

    discoveryAgent->start(QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::LowEnergyMethod);
}
```

2) the slot addDevice() which extract devices found:

```
void CemBluetooth::addDevice(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo& device)
{
    std::cout << "Device discovered: ";
    //if (device.coreConfigurations() & QBluetoothDeviceInfo::LowEnergyCoreConfiguration) // i shunt this condition for the moment, in order to detect all device.
    //{
        QString name1 = device.name();
        std::cout << name1.toStdString() << std::endl;
    //}
}
```

Can you help me to find out the solution, please?

Comment: I do not know how BT implemented in QT but Windows has different APIs fro Classic and LE devices. So I guess QT must also have different methods for classic and LE discovering.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mike.
I get BLE functions from a Qt BLE example.

Comment: Hard to say what can be wrong but I guess QT 4.12 does not support modern WinRT BLE discovering and can discover only paired BLE devices. Try latest QT that supports WinRT BLE discovering (at least it looks supported in QT source code).

Comment: Sorry, you've right, it's in fact Qt 5.14.2 that I use.. The version I gave it's "Qt Creator" version...

Comment: All I could find in QT sources is that QT_WINRT_BLUETOOTH must be define.

Comment: I looked on the code deeper and found that it uses a bit wrong methods to discover LE device. Use LE Device Watcher (do not know how but it is available there) instead of discovering.

Comment: Ok thank you Mike I will try in that direction and come back do my feedback

Comment: Here are all classes for handle bluetooth on Qt [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-module.html) There is no LE Device Watcher, I don't understand..

Comment: As I wrote I am not familiar with QT, i have just looked on its source and there (https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtconnectivity/src/bluetooth/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent_winrt.cpp.html) you can see that it can use IBluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher for BLE devices discovering. But by default it uses absolutely wrong method with IDeviceInformationStatics. I have no idea how to switch QT to right direction.

Comment: I've just restart my projet and begin with the Bluetooth part and let the graphical part for the end and it works!
I don't know what was the issue for the moment but I will publish the reason later when I will have investigate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved! I just change my compiler from minGW to MSVC and it works fine. The precise reason is still unknown for me, but the solution is here.

Answer (score 0):

Some info for future visitors:

"Win32 backend has been removed. There will not be a working Bluetooth backend when Qt is built with mingw."

Link: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtbluetooth-changes-qt6.html